# Remove negative symbol (-) from NSDecimalNumber gives me an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I have an `array` with `NSDecimalNumbers` inside. I will do a check to see if that number is a negative number. If it is, I want to remove the negative sign (-). Here is my code:

```
NSString *amount = [myArray objectAtInde:2]; // Is a NSDecimalNumber with value of: -397.67

    if ([amount doubleValue] < 0) {
        amount = [amount stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"- $"];
    }
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcaf94eff80'
```

Comment: If your array has NSDecimalNumbers, why are you assigning it to an NSString?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to remove the "-" sign. What I really want to is assign `amount` to a `label`, then if the value is negative, I want the `label` to show like this: `- $397.67` and not `$ -397.67. Get what I'm saying?

Comment: Then use an `NSNumberFormatter` setup for currency style. Then the currency value will be properly formatted for the user's locale. Don't do your own formatting. It will be wrong for most users.

Comment: @rmaddy is right. You shouldn't be trying to format numbers like this. Use `NSNumberFormatter`. As for your crash, the log says it all. You're calling a method from `NSString` on `NSDecimalNumber`. Obviously it's going to crash. PS. rmaddy, I'm a bit late, but congrats on crossing 100k rep. I remember the time you were ~20k. Good going man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSDecimalNumber *amountNumber = [myArray objectAtIndex:2]; // Is a NSDecimalNumber with value of: -397.67

NSString *stringWithDollarSymbol = [self addDollarSymoblForNumber:amountNumber];
```

You can assign the `stringWithDollarSymbol` to label

```
- (NSString *)addDollarSymoblForNumber:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNum
{
    NSString *modifiedString = @"";
    if (decimalNum) {
        NSString *numberInStringForm = [decimalNum stringValue];
            if ([decimalNum doubleValue] < 0) { //adds dollor symbol for negative numbers
            modifiedString = [numberInStringForm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"- $"];
        }
        else //adds dollor symbol for positive numbers
        {
            modifiedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",modifiedString];
        }
    }
    return modifiedString;
}
```

**EDIT**

More Better Approach using `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
- (NSString *)formatNumberBasedOnCurrentLocale:(NSDecimalNumber *)number
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter  alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
    if (result.length >0) {
        return result;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: It would be MUCH better to use an `NSNumberFormatter` setup for currency formatting. Then the value will be formatted based on the user's locale.

Answer (score 1):

Add below method in your source file

```
    // multiplies number with -1 if it is less than zero else returns the same 
    - (NSDecimalNumber *)abs:(NSDecimalNumber *)num 
    {
        if ([num compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) 
        {
            // Number is negative. Multiply by -1
            NSDecimalNumber * negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                              exponent:0
                                                                            isNegative:YES];
            return [num decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
        } 
        else 
        {
            return num;
        }
    }
```

And convert instance of `NSDecimalNumbers` to `abs` value without doing any type conversion as-

```
NSDecimalNumbers *number = [myArray objectAtInde:2];

number = [number abs:number];
```

the `number` returned will contain `abs` value in `NSDecimalNumbers` format.

Answer (score 0):

Please add line,

```
if ([amount doubleValue] < 0) {
    amount=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:2]];//add line
    amount = [amount stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
}
```

it may be work for you,

Answer (score 0):

I just used your code & it's working fine at my end.

Tried below thing,

```
NSString *amount = @"-397.67";//[myArray objectAtInde:2]; // Is a NSDecimalNumber with value of: -397.67

    if ([amount doubleValue] < 0) {
        amount = [amount stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    }
```

Try it at your end.

If nothing will work then multiply your negative float value with -1 & you will get positive number. If that is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[myArray objectAtInde:2]` is a `NSDecimalNumber` rather than `NSString`, try this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *amountNumber = [myArray objectAtInde:2];
NSString *amount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", amountNumber];
```

Comment: The goal is to get the absolute value, not convert it to a string.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right, nevertheless, I don't know his goal

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to rescue from the negative then just simply convert the value into an absolute value.

```
NSString *amount = [myArray objectAtIndex:2]; // Is a NSDecimalNumber with value of: -397.67

NSLog(@"The value is : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", fabs([amount doubleValue])]);
```

The value is: 397.67

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
NSString *amount = @(ABS([myArray[2] doubleValue])).stringValue ; // Is a NSDecimalNumber with value of: -397.67
```

Comment: Replace `ABS` with `abs`. Case matters.

Comment: @rmaddy, You are right that the case is matters, but abs is for int only!

Comment: Yes, my mistake. `fabs` is for `double`.